# How to create a simple nodes-to-sink communication pattern (multi-hop topology) in Castalia Simulator

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I am facing some teething problems in Castalia Simulator, while creating a simple nodes-to-sink communication pattern.

I want to create a unidirectional topology as describe follows

```
node 0 <-------> node 1<----------->node 2<-------->node 3               

source =node 0

relay node= node 1, 2

Sink node = node 3
```

Here messages flow from left to right, so node 0 sends only to node 1, node 1 sends only to node 2, and node 2 sends only to node 3. **When node 0 want to send data packet to node 3, then node 1 and node 2 worked as intermediate nodes (relay nodes/ forwarding nodes).** The neighbor nodes can also send data in unidirectional fashion (left to right) such as node 0 sends to node 1, node 1 sends to node 2 etc.

I read manual and understand the ApplicationName ="ThroughputTest" , but according to my understanding here, all nodes will send data to sink (node 0).

I added following lines in omnetpp.init  file:-

```
SN.node[0].Application.nextRecipient = "1"

SN.node[1].Application.nextRecipient = "2"

SN.node[2].Application.nextRecipient = "3"

SN.node[3].Application.nextRecipient = "3"
```

But I am not getting my desire result.

Please help me regard this .

Regards

Gulshan Soni

Comment: What language is it?

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information to figure out what you have done.

The part of your omnetpp.ini file you copied here, just shows that you are defining some static app-level routing using the app module `ThroughputTest`

There are so many other parts to a network. Firstly, the definition of the MAC plays a crucial role. For example, if you have chosen MAC 802.15.4 or BaselineBANMAC, you cannot have multihop routing, since there is only hub to slave nodes communication. Furthermore, how you define the radio and the channel, can also impact communication. For example, the signal might not be strong enough to reach from one node to another.

Read the [Castalia User's Manual](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/) carefully, and provide enough information in your questions so that others can replicate your results.

Comment: I am using BypassRouting and TMAC  protocols. The distance between nodes is 15 meter. I am having some queries   1) I  saw Castalia-Trace.txt file, but i did not find any information about  intermediate /relay nodes (node 1,2). 2). I used CastaliaResults scripts to find out detail of packets send.
Why this is showing Packet loss rate = 1, Packets received per node =70 and Packets reception rate =0. 
3) The sink node (node 3) is receiving very less packets ( 70 packets), I think the reason is "early sleep problem" in TMAC. Am i correct here ?